# DML Trigger in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my code

```
ALTER TRIGGER [CoSD].[BusinessLogicUtilTrigger] 
ON [CoSD].[ERSConstructedVariablesOutcomes]
AFTER INSERT, UPDATE
AS
    ;WITH dataforIDs AS
    (
        SELECT 
            value, ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries
        FROM  
            [AnimalProductsCoSD].[CoSD].[ERSBusinessLogic]
        CROSS APPLY
            (SELECT
                 Seq = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)),
                 Value = v.value('(./text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(MAX)')
             FROM
                 (VALUES (CONVERT(XML, '<x>' + replace(ERSBusinessLogic_InputDataSeries,',','</x><x>')+'</x>'))) x(n)
        CROSS APPLY
            n.nodes('x') node(v)) B
        WHERE
            ERSBusinessLogic_InputGeographyDimensionID = 7493
            AND ERSBusinessLogic_InputTimeDimensionValue = 'all months'
            AND ERSBusinessLogic_Type = 'HS10 aggregation'
    )
```

Is there any way to modify this trigger that it calls after a stored procedure completes its execution. Right now I feel it is called as soon one row is inserted.

In short I want a trigger which will call after the stored procedure is executed OR is there any way else to achieve this ?

Comment: If you want code to run after a stored procedure runs, that sounds like another stored procedure (not a trigger). That is, call the new proc at the end of the existing one.

Comment: Your code is just a cte, where is the rest? What exactly is the problem you are having?

Comment: @BenThul That procedure is messed up and that looping is causing issues to the code I wrote, so I thought to run a trigger after a stored procedure is executed. Anyhow I have tried to call another procedure after that procedure, it still did not work.

Comment: @HoneyBadger The code is very big, I just wanted some changes in the trigger so it runs after the stored procedure completes its execution and not during the execution.

Comment: Sounds like you should fix the procedure. Normally, there's no reason for looping. It's very difficult to help without complete code. Please see [mcve] for some pointers on reducing the code.

Comment: @HoneyBadger Or any piece of code that I can add in the trigger(which I can change to procedure) which will run immediately after that stored procedure runs. ?

Comment: If you are looking for something like `if caller = 'stored procedure' ...` or `call trigger somename...` then no, you cannot do that. You also shouldn't *want* to do that.

Comment: @HoneyBadger The only way is to change the procedure is it ?

Comment: @user3715927 That's right. In all likelihood your procedure will also perform better without looping. Though that depends on why it is looping in the first place.

Comment: From what you posted, we have no idea what the procedure does nor what the trigger will do, so there's no way to make useful suggestions. If your trigger - from which we see just a cte (=named subquery) - is going to just select some records… no, this will not work. If that's what you want, place the SELECT query at the end of your procedure instead.